# Angular basic expression split

Tags: angularjs, list, split, match

I have a textarea that preview the text that is typed. Then i want to count the rows and a new row is defined by either a \n or when 32char it hit.

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="inputText1" rows="4" maxlength="64" ng-model="textBase"></textarea>
<pre>{{textBase}}</pre>

Rows after break or 32char: {{(textBase ? textBase.split("\n").length : 0)}}
```

After this it counts the rows after each break. But how can i add so its either after break or after 32char?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very hard to handle using inline expressions.

I would suggest to use a ng-change and outsource the calculation to a controller function. I have create a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bdmqxr5y/12270/) to solve this problem. Since I did not know your correct working flow (counting a row with 32 chars as one or two rows?, ...) you need to adjust this example to your own needs.

View:

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="inputText1" rows="4" maxlength="64" ng-model="textBase" ng-change="evaluateChange()"></textarea>
<pre>{{textBase}}</pre>

Rows after break or 32char: {{rowsAfterBreakOr32}}
```

Controller:

```
$scope.textBase = '';
$scope.rowsAfterBreakOr32 = 0;

$scope.evaluateChange = function() {
    // calc row break or 32chars
    var rowBreaks = $scope.textBase ? $scope.textBase.split("\n") : [$scope.textBase];
    $scope.rowsAfterBreakOr32 = rowBreaks.length;

    // iterate each row and count chars
    for(var i=0; i<rowBreaks.length; i++) {
      if(rowBreaks[i].length > 32) {
        $scope.rowsAfterBreakOr32 += rowBreaks[i].match(/.{1,32}/g).length;
      }
    }
};
```

Comment: I was afraid that it might be to hard to make with basic expressions.

Comment: Why you want to use a deep construct of basic expressions when you can use an easy to understand change function? Think about readability.

Comment: i wanted to see if i could only use some basic instead of making a controller without defining to much, but instead just the data from the html to make calculation. I guess it was one step to much with row counting to make it work easy in basic, just wanted to make sure before i started to dig into a controller. They way you did it works very good with a few modification to suite me better, but it does exactly what i want and i can build on it. Thank you.